# Proxy reset to loopback address in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, proxy, virus

Proxy server is set again and again to 127.0.0.1 in `Windows 8.1`. I am able to edit it but it is reset immediately after I navigate away from the settings screen.

Some solutions suggested setting `Proxy Enable` to `0` in `Internet Settings`from the `Registry`. I tried using registry cleaners like `ccleaner` but haven't found any working solution. I think it is some kind of virus. I also tried using some `antivirus` but that didn't work either.

The operating system is activated and updated one. How can I deal with the issue?

Comment: I would suggest run Process Monitor (https://technet.microsoft.com/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx).  Add a Path contains `\Internet Settings\ProxyServer` filter.  What process changes it with a RegSetValue Operation?  Maybe it's rundll32.exe, as would be the case typically, maybe something is changing it directly but this will let you know.

Comment: Thanks for introducing a good tool! The `vlc.exe` was modifying the proxy server values.

Comment: Glad it helped.  I assume vlc.exe was the genuine VLC based on the Digital signature of the file?  Maybe upload vlc.exe to  https://www.virustotal.com/ as a double-check.

Comment: virustotal.com reports file to be safe. I will wait to for some more days(or many restarts of computer) , may be the problem might pop up again. Actually I am trying to acquire developer license for windows 8.1, may be some of processes related to visual studio like `devenv` is changing the proxy values, if it was not really the `vlc.exe`.